# Missing artifact in maven but jar present in local repository

Tags: maven

I have a J2EE project managed by Maven imported from a location on my local file system which I got from a download from the web. There was an interruption when the building workspace phase was going on and eclipse had to be abnormally shut down.

Now the problem is that some folders on the local repository are with out the necessary jar files but during the building workspace phase the local repo is not being completed. I see that the local repo has some completed folders for the jar dependencies but the m2e plugin in eclipse says missing artifact even though those jars are present in the local repo.

I went trough all the related questions on this forum and others as well and tried out the relevant solutions but couldn't solve the problem.

Can some one help me out with this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Things to try: 1- Delete your local repository and let maven recreate it; 2- Use an external maven installation instead of pure m2e plugin; 3- Delete the target folders on your project; 4-Run maven on the command line outside eclipse and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting everything in your local maven repository so that any corrupt files get reloaded.

This directory is usually located somewhere like:
    C:\Users{Your User}.m2\repository

Then try another mvn clean install

Comment: I did try that out but it didnot solve my problem . The local repository gets filled up incompletely as it was before . I have noticed that the repository returns to the same position as it was before the deletion .